# powershell create xml and parent and child elements if they do not exist

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I wonder if anyone could help.
PowerShell creation of XML from Exchange mailbox information

I have been advised of a requirement where we need to audit the access of each mailbox within our Exchange environment.
I have managed to grab each mailbox and add to the XML , the problem I have is the rest!
For each mailbox, I need to do the following

> - get DisplayName, PrimarySMTP, Alias
> - check if mailbox is already in XML file, if not add `<Mailbox DisplayName="Jerry The Mouse" PrimarySMTP="jerrythemouse@domain.com" Alias="jerrythemouse" />`
> - Check OWA is enabled
> - check if OWA within the mailbox section is already in XML file, if not add `<Access ServiceName="OWA" />`
> - get the current day of month and add entry to OWA `<Report Day="DAY of REPORT" Enabled="true/false" />`
> - Check IMAP is enabled
> - check if IMAP within the mailbox section is already in XML file, if not add `<Access ServiceName="IMAP" />`
> - get the current day of month and add entry to IMAP `<Report Day="DAY of REPORT" Enabled="true/false" />`
> - Check POP is enabled
> - check if POP within the mailbox section is already in XML file, if not add `<Access ServiceName="POP" />`
> - get the current day of month and add entry to IMAP `<Report Day="DAY of REPORT" Enabled="true/false" />`
> - Check MAPI is enabled
> - check if MAPI within the mailbox section is already in XML file, if not add `<Access ServiceName="MAPI" />`
> - get the current day of month and add entry to IMAP `<Report Day="DAY of REPORT" Enabled="true/false" />`
> - When finished, save XML

I dont need help with the Exchange side, just the creation of the elements (if they do not exist) as per my list above!
The XML file will be trashed on the 1st day of the following month.
The reason for the format is because of an additional requirement from another department who will take the xml and draw graphs for the number of days that month.
Hoping someone can help

Thanks

A copy of the xml should look like the following.

```
<root>
    <Mailbox DisplayName="Jerry The Mouse" PrimarySMTP="jerrythemouse@domain.com" Alias="jerrythemouse">
        <Access ServiceName="OWA">
            <Report Day="01" Date="01/10/2016" Enabled="true" />
            <Report Day="02" Date="02/10/2016" Enabled="true" />
            <Report Day="03" Date="03/10/2016" Enabled="false" />
        </Access>
        <Access ServiceName="IMAP">
            <Report Day="01" Date="01/10/2016" Enabled="false" />
            <Report Day="02" Date="02/10/2016" Enabled="false" />
            <Report Day="03" Date="03/10/2016" Enabled="false" />
        </Access>
        <Access ServiceName="POP">
            <Report Day="01" Date="01/10/2016" Enabled="true" />
            <Report Day="02" Date="02/10/2016" Enabled="true" />
            <Report Day="03" Date="03/10/2016" Enabled="true" />
        </Access>
        <Access ServiceName="MAPI">
            <Report Day="01" Date="01/10/2016" Enabled="true" />
            <Report Day="02" Date="02/10/2016" Enabled="true" />
            <Report Day="03" Date="03/10/2016" Enabled="true" />
        </Access>
    </Mailbox>
    <Mailbox DisplayName="Tom The Cat" PrimarySMTP="tomthecat@domain.com" Alias="tomthecat">
        <Access ServiceName="OWA">
            <Report Day="01" Date="01/10/2016" Enabled="true" />
            <Report Day="02" Date="02/10/2016" Enabled="true" />
            <Report Day="03" Date="03/10/2016" Enabled="false" />
        </Access>
        <Access ServiceName="IMAP">
            <Report Day="01" Date="01/10/2016" Enabled="false" />
            <Report Day="02" Date="02/10/2016" Enabled="false" />
            <Report Day="03" Date="03/10/2016" Enabled="false" />
        </Access>
        <Access ServiceName="POP">
            <Report Day="01" Date="01/10/2016" Enabled="true" />
            <Report Day="02" Date="02/10/2016" Enabled="true" />
            <Report Day="03" Date="03/10/2016" Enabled="true" />
        </Access>
        <Access ServiceName="MAPI">
            <Report Day="01" Date="01/10/2016" Enabled="true" />
            <Report Day="02" Date="02/10/2016" Enabled="true" />
            <Report Day="03" Date="03/10/2016" Enabled="true" />
        </Access>
    </Mailbox>
    ...
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether nodes exist using XPath queries:

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content $filename)

$xml.SelectNodes("//root/Mailbox[@DisplayName='Jerry The Mouse']").Count
1

$xml.SelectNodes("//root/Mailbox[@DisplayName='Jerry The Mouse']/Access[@ServiceName='OWA']").Count
1
```

That is, if this is non-zero then the node exists at least once.

Adding new elements is more laborious:

```
# Adding a new mailbox
$newMbx = $xml.CreateElement('Mailbox')

$attDisplayName = $xml.CreateAttribute('DisplayName')
$attPrimarySmtp = $xml.CreateAttribute('PrimarySmtp')
# etc.

$attDisplayName.Value = 'Spike The Dog'
$attPrimarySmtp.Value = 'SpikeTheDog@domain.com'
# etc.

$newMbx.Attributes.Append($attDisplayName)
$newMbx.Attributes.Append($attPrimarySmtp)
# etc.

$newSvc = $xml.CreateElement('Access')
$attServiceName = $xml.CreateAttribute('ServiceName')
$attServiceName.Value = 'OWA'
$newSvc.Attributes.Append($attServiceName)

# Add this back into the XML document:
$xml.LastChild.Append($newMbx)
```

Adding an new element within a Mailbox/Access element:

```
# Create a new $record XML element using the technique above

# Add this new element to an existing XML element:

$xml.SelectNodes("//root/Mailbox[@DisplayName='Spike The Dog']/Access[@ServiceName='OWA']").AppendChild($record)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  
I will not be able to look at this until Monday/Tuesday as I am travelling to Microsoft FutureDecoded!

Comment: Ask Steven Hawking if he can query XML data with XPATH!

Comment: Haha! I would but I wont be there on Day 1!